# How to convert AC3 audio to Wav audio?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, wav, sox

I would like to convert a AC3 audio file (ATSC A/52 aka AC-3 aka Dolby Digital stream 6 channels) to Wave audio file (16khz mono/1 channel).

While searching on the internet, a lot of people just used `ffmpeg -i file.ac3 file.wav` however, i'm not sure if that even works.

I keep getting

```
[ac3 @ 0x55ac1a0b0660] exponent -1 is out-of-rangets/s speed= 125x
[ac3 @ 0x55ac1a0b0660] error decoding the audio block
[ac3 @ 0x55ac1a0b0660] frame sync error
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
etc
```

while I do the same command.
How do I convert ac3 to wav (16khz mono)?

*Note:
I also tried `ffmpeg -i file.ac3 -codec:a:1 ac3 -codec copy -b:a 384 file.wav -ac 1 -ar 16000`. But this doesn't output an actual wav file.

Answer (score 3):

`ffmpeg -i file.ac3 -vcodec copy -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16000 -ab 128k -ac 1 file.wav` should do it!

Answer (score 0):

Also you can convert Eac3 to wav in high quality mode.
The wav file will be 48KHz 24Bit 6 Channels.

```
ffmpeg -i "input.eac3" -acodec pcm_s24le -ar 48000 -ac 6 "output.wav"
```

If you want to export in 8 channels, just write 8 instead of 6.